# Error trying to get action & reducer working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following a blog post, attempting to get a user login implemented in my app

https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/

It recommends doing the following in my action

```
// actions.js

export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST'

function requestLogin(creds) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    isFetching: true,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    creds
  }
}

// .....

export function loginUser(creds) {

  let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `username=${creds.username}&password=${creds.password}`
  }
  console.log(creds) // <-- this works
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(creds) // <-- this doesnt work and everything after it doesnt work

    // We dispatch requestLogin to kickoff the call to the API
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds))

    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/sessions/create', config)
      .then(response =>
        response.json().then(user => ({ user, response }))
            ).then(({ user, response }) =>  {
        if (!response.ok) {
          // If there was a problem, we want to
          // dispatch the error condition
          dispatch(loginError(user.message))
          return Promise.reject(user)
        } else {
          // If login was successful, set the token in local storage
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.id_token)
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.access_token)
          // Dispatch the success action
          dispatch(receiveLogin(user))
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log("Error: ", err))
  }
}
```

However, as soon as the function hits the part `return dispatch => {` an error gets raised
[image]

--- Edit ---
the answers below fixed the console errors, but a new error was introduced

my redux chrome plugin no longer sees my redux store
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not set up Redux Thunk which is a Redux library that allows you to have asynchronous actions.

In the tutorial you [linked](https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/), it is explained how to set it up:

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'


let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, api)(createStore)
```

You should read more about Redux Thunk [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Comment: that sounds like it would do it, i'll check it out! thanks!

Comment: you were correct on the source of the error, but a new issue got introduced -- I edited OP

Comment: You need to use `composeEnhancers` now. See here https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is to utilise a thunk, which is a function that returns another function.

In redux that is used to cause side effects during action creation such as asynchronous calls as part of an action, and producing secondary actions, like dispatching the response from this asynchronous request.

If you look in the blog post package.json they have dependency on redux-thunk middleware package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) you will need this too, and to attach it to your store...

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Comment: In the blog post check out 'index.js'. The above shows minimal code needed to avoid that error from a redux point of view, but if you are wanting to follow their setup more closely, they do the same thing along with some extra bootstrapping